# Xubuntu Xfce - multiple actions for shortcut

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, shortcuts

I would like to apply an additional command for default Xfce "left_workspace" (to show the toolbar on which I have a preview of all workspaces). I tried editing the configuration file (xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml), but the system overwrites it on re-login. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I had edited your question above assuming you meant 'different command' when you said 'additional command.' I'm sorry if I was mistaken. Are you wanting to go to the left workspace and show the toolbar with a preview of all workspaces with one command or just replace the left workspace command with your toolbar command?

Comment: I would like the shortcut to do 2 things:
1.go to next workspace
2.display toolbar with preview of all workspaces

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope all works out great.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting up:**
1. Install `wmctrl` by pasting `sudo apt-get install wmctrl` in terminal.
 
2. Copy the script below to your `bin` directory in your home directory. Create `bin` if necessary. 
3. Make the script executable `chmod +x ~/bin/script-name`

**Editing script:**
1. Replace the two instances of `panel-5` with the number of your panel that has the workspaces on it.
2. Change `sleep 5` to the amount of time in seconds you want to panel to be displayed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Switch to the next workspace and make your panel appear
wmctrl -s `wmctrl -d | awk '$2=="*"{cur=NR} END{print cur % NR}'` &
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-5/autohide-behavior -s 0

# Amount of time the panel appears before hiding again
sleep 5

# Hides the panel
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-5/autohide-behavior -s 2
```

**How to use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> keyboard shortcut:**
1. Go to Window Manager > Keyboard. Change Left workspace to some random keyboard shortcut.
2. Now you can add your keyboard shortcut under Keyboard > Application Shortcuts. You can just paste the `script-name`.

Comment: but the system does not know the file has updated so it does not change configuration. How do i restart keyboard shortcuts initialization to make system read the file again?

Comment: I have now posted a new answer above.